# VBA code to copy and paste certain data from sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I know there has to be a simpler and more efficient way of writing this code, but not familiar with the correct functions (like how to paste to the next worksheet without pasting over existing data).  It works for smaller worksheets but I have to use it on worksheets with 60000+ lines.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
Sub test()
    Dim row As Long
    With Excel.Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

For row = 1 To 65500
If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 14) <> "" Then
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).EntireRow.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SCO").Cells(row, 1)
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SCO").Cells(row + 1, 1)

End If

Next

For row = 1 To 65500
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SCO").Cells(row, 14) = "" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SCO").Cells(row, 20).Value = 2
End If
Next
For x = 65500 To 1 Step -1
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SCO").Cells(x, 3) = "" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SCO").Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
For row = 1 To 65500
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SCO").Cells(row, 20) = 2 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SCO").Cells(row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
End If

Next

With Excel.Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = Excel.xlAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using an autofilter to filter the data out that you want and then use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy` to get copy the filtered data onto a new sheet. Also when you do need to loop through all of your data instead of going all the way to 65500 go to `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` so you don't loop through empty cells.

Example:

The first loop you have looks like it copies all rows that do not have blanks in column 14.

```
For row = 1 To 65500
    If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 14) <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).EntireRow.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SCO").Cells(row, 1)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SCO").Cells(row + 1, 1)
    End If
Next
```

Instead of looping through all of the data you could filter it and copy the result like this:

```
'Filter out blank rows in column 14
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="<>"

'Copy and Paste the results to Sheet "SCO"
If Sheets("SCO").Range("A1").Value = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("SCO").Range("A1")
Else
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("SCO").Cells(Sheets("SCO").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)
End If
```

Also here where you loop through 1 to 65500

```
For row = 1 To 65500
    If Sheets("SCO").Cells(row, 14) = "" Then
        Sheets("SCO").Cells(row, 20).Value = 2
    End If
Next
```

You could do this to reduce the amount of times you need to loop

```
For row = 1 To Sheets("SCO").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Sheets("SCO").Cells(row, 14) = "" Then
        Sheets("SCO").Cells(row, 20).Value = 2
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the UsedRange and Count function.  I can guess what they do but not sure about the syntax.  So I should replace the for loop with Activesheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count?  Is it possible to tell me exactly where I should place these commands within my code?